# Google Chrome misbehaving: clean exit, save passwords, sync,

Tags: fedora, chrome

I have recently upgraded to Fedora 29 and have Google Chrome Version 71.0.3578.98 (Official Build) (64-bit) installed. It is misbehaving in a number of ways:

1. It will not exit cleanly. after using *menu* -> Exit then several processes are left running. It takes 2 calls to `killall chrome` to get them to die. It makes no difference which way I have the "Continue running background apps when Google Chrome is closed" setting set.
2. It will not offer to save passwords (including specifically for websites where this worked previously). "Offer to save passwords" is enabled.
3. If I enable Chrome sign-in then *Settings -> Sync* just shows: "Advanced sync settings; Please wait…". If I leave it long enough the "Please wait…" is replaced by "Check your Internet connection. If the problem continues, try signing out and signing in again." I guess this is some sort of clue. In general, my Internet connection is working just fine.
4. If I use Ctrl-N to create a new window, the new window is created hidden behind the current one.

Solutions that I have tried, all without success:

1. Reinstall Chrome
2. Remove (rename) my Chrome configuration (`~/.config/google-chrome`), thus creating a completely new profile and configuration, just copying in my old bookmarks file.
3. Removing any chrome-related cache files that I can find.

[Edited to add]
I have NFS-mounted home directories.

Comment: I have same problem on Linux Mint. I am not on NFS-mounted dir. Version 74.0.3729.131 (Official Build) (64-bit). When I try to sync Chrome I get message ""Check your internet connection. If the problem continues, try signing out and signing in again.", although Google login and everything else works well

Answer (score 0):

This was all fixed by the next Chrome update. I don't recall which version that was - I'm now at 73.0.3683.86.